# array of SystemSounds

Tags: c#, arrays, system-sounds

I would like to play a different sound based on the value of a variable. I could do independent IF statements but I'd like to do it in an array.
I have a global

```
SystemSound[] sound_array=new SystemSound[5];
```

and in form.load I do

```
sound_array[0] = SystemSounds.Beep;
sound_array[1] = SystemSounds.Asterisk;
sound_array[2] = SystemSounds.Exclamation;
sound_array[3] = SystemSounds.Hand;
sound_array[4] = SystemSounds.Question;
```

then in the main code I have

```
SystemSounds.sound_array[i].Play();
```

if I do 
    SystemSounds.beep.Play();

it works fine, I just can't figure out how to do it in an array.
I get Error 1   'System.Media.SystemSounds' does not contain a definition for 'sound_array' 
Thanks

Comment: What is your error output?

Comment: for (SystemSound s : sound_array) { s.Play() };

Comment: just `sound_array[i].Play();` should do it.

Comment: And I assume from syntax that this is java, but please retag if not. *edit* oh no it's C#. Please add a language tag in future.

Comment: The error is right at the end of the post

Comment: sound_array[i].Play(); looks like it did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you have

```
SystemSound[] sound_array=new SystemSound[5];
```

`sound_array` is a local variable. The correct way to use it is `sound_array` instead of `SystemSounds.sound_array`:

```
sound_array[i].Play();
```